# Spring 4 + @ControllerAdvice: Jsonp support for ResponseBody causes Deployment Exception?

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, jsonp, spring-4

I am adding JSONP support to a REST Service in SPRING4 + JDK 8 + STS 3.6.4

Versions:
Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

My implementation is based on these links:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-jsonp

The REST service returns ResponseEntity or ResponseBody and use case is to return data in JSONP format.

Added a ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JsonpCallbackAdvice extends AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice {

    public JsonpCallbackAdvice(){
       super("Callback");
    }
}
```

Here is the Controller of the REST Service

```
@Controller
public class AcctController {
 ...
   @RequestMapping(value = "/act/{actNum}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Account> getAccount(@PathVariable("actNum") Integer accountNum) throws Exception {
...
return new ResponseEntity<account>();
}
```

Here is the relevant web application context configuration

```
...
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />
<bean name="jsonMessageConverter"
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
...
```

The controller and ControllerAdvice are in same package.

When deployment of the project is initiated following exception is observed

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:69)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:246)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
```

This exception was not happening before the ControllerAdvice was added.
Also, it does not happens when @ControllerAdvice annotation is removed
or
the component scan excludes scanning package of the ControllerAdvice class

I tried with Spring version 4.2.0.RC1, and the exception still happens.

Kindly help with resolution of this exception, since not much help is available online. 
It seems like a bug in SPRING 4, however am not sure.

Comment: could you update your question and add all XML context files? The exception seems to be related to the bean parsing phase. Note that you don't need to configure your own Jackson MessageConverter, it's done for you with `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` if Jackson 2 is on classpath.

Comment: I agree to your comment. It seems like we are using another implementation of the JacksonMessageConverter and it is causing the issue. I created a sample Spring application that is not using any of our existing classes or frameworks and the same implementation worked.